# Accessing class method from an instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I have the following code

```
class Monster
  def self.yell
    'i am yelling!'
  end

  def shout_something
    Monster.yell
  end
end
```

My `yell` method is a class method while `shout_something` is an instance method that calls `yell`.

Is there anything inherently wrong with doing something like this? For example, is it bad to call a class method from an instance method? I ask because it feels wrong but maybe it's just because I'm a newbie to ruby.

On a side note, I thought doing `self.yell` instead of `Monster.yell` would make more sense but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing particularly wrong about calling a class method from an instance method. Depending on your intent and how you want people to subclass your Monster, you might want to use this:

```
def shout_something
    self.class.yell
end
```

So that subclasses can provide their `yell` class method.